# Sequence is giving already given numbers

Tags: postgresql

I'm using a sequence `datasource_id_seq` created by hand to create unique table names by concatenating a string with numbers returned by the sequence via `select nextval('datasource_id_seq')`.

The code to create it is on my very first migration:

```
create sequence datasource_id_seq;
```

And there's nothing like that again in the whole code base.

I recently stump into a bug that ended being the sequence was giving numbers already given. It was returning values in the 6xx (six hundreds) while we already have tables with names over 3xxx (three thousands).

Reading the docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-sequence.html) the only thing I could catch that points to a reset in the sequence is:

> If a sequence object has been created with default parameters, successive nextval calls will return successive values beginning with 1

So, the only ways to reset a sequence is to recreate it or to use `setval()`, none of which are in the code base.

**My question is:** how can happen a sequence resets? What other means are to reset a sequence

Comment: Maybe the application created some of these tables entries without using the sequence?

Comment: I will remain a mystery. I just wanted to confirm there were no other means to reset the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With properly working, bug-free PostgreSQL server it is not possible to allocate the same sequence number two or more times. It's not even "returned" in case of a rollback. The only method to manipulate next value is using the functions you've already mentioned.

Look for the problem during deployment of your app. I'd speculate that the sequence got dropped and recreated.